# Use .replacingOccurrences with dynamic replacement value

Tags: swift

I want to add the line numbers to a String.
For example:
`let content = "hello\n\nworld"`
should result in
`content = "1:hello\n2:\n3:world"`

.replacingOccurrences does not allow replacing `\n` with a dynamic value, in my case an incremental number.
E.g.,

```
var counter = 0
content = "1: " content.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "getNumber(): $0")
__________________________

func getNumber() -> Int {
        counter += 1
        return counter
}
```

results in
`1:hello\n1:\n1:world` as `getNumber` is only called once by `replacingOccurrences`.
Splitting the String and then adding the line number is not a solution as it "eats" empty lines `\n\n`.

How can archive the above described expected result?

Comment: I am curious about the \n at the end of the string that you seem to ignore in your example. How should it be treated?

Comment: You are going to have to iterate through the string for each `\n` and insert the next number. It can't be done with a one-line call.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would be fine if it gets a line number so that I simply can drop the last line at the end. I removed it from the example to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

1. `split` the string by `\n`
2. `enumerate` the array to get also the indices
3. `map` each string to `index+1` plus `:` plus the `element`
4. `join` the array back to a string

---

```
let content = "hello\n\nworld"

let result = content
    .split(separator: "\n", omittingEmptySubsequences: false) // or .components(separatedBy: "\n")
    .enumerated()
    .map {"\($0.0+1):\($0.1)"}
    .joined(separator: "\n")
```

To get rid of empty lines set `omittingEmptySubsequences` to `true`.